# Can I expand a div to full screen that is nested underneath another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a design I want to code and want the blue div to expand on click, despite it being nexted behind the yellow div. Can anyone help with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoGsf.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Pictures do not help much, please show us your attempt on creating this yourself, and then we can help you with the problem you face

Comment: Please give details. Anyway it looks like you need to use `position` CSS property.

Comment: You can use `z-index` and `position` properties of css to achieve this.

Comment: Will do. I couldn't find my original draft of the website but I'll recode it and ask again. I just ran into problems last time expanding the bottom div after coding position relative and absolute in css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```js
$('.back').on('click',function(){
 if ( $(this).hasClass('expanded') ) { $(this).removeClass('expanded'); }
 else $(this).addClass('expanded');
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.back {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:0;
  top:0px;
  left:20px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:20px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.expanded {
  z-index:2;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box front"></div>
<div class="box back"></div>
```

Comment: yes! Perfect. I'll just hide the yellow div after and expand left as well. thank you.

Comment: I tried it, not working. Don't know how to show you my code from here. First time using stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe you can try jsfiddle.net as well, to show your code

Comment: Heike, I had edited your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/358edf2g/1/) a little, now it works. Problems was:
1. You have to set up required JQuery library (Javascript box, Settings icon). Of course, on your real page you also have to link it. On [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) you can get help for it.
2. Your jQuery code is waiting for the onclick event on a *'button**, but your HTML contains no button. I added one for you. Or you can modify the event listener element to anything else.
3. In the CSS box you mistyped the line 49. Only one **{** is needed.

Comment: May I add the button inside the blue? I removed the button I had initially as it wasn't working. I'll make sure to link the library. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Of course you can move the button to the blue part.